Number of possible histograms of a test given that the median is 60
There is the following problem I'm having a hard time coming up with a Sigma-less solution to:
If $360$ have taken a test, and grades can range from $0-100$ (inclusive), how many possible  histograms exist if the median is $60$?
My attempt on the problem is like so:
If the median is $60$, then the sum of the $180$th and the $181$st should be $120$ - so that the average between them (since we have an even number of students) is $60$. Let $i$ denote the grade student $180$ got, $20\leq i\leq 60$ (lower than 20 would cause the $181st$ have grade above $100$, and higher than $60$ would cause $181$st have grade below $180$th. So the $181$th has grade $120 - i$.
Now let's count the historgrams for the $179$ students who got less than or equal to $i$ (between $0-i$ inclusive): it's a choice with repetitions and without regard to the order at which we choose, so according to the stars and bars result: $${179 + i + 1 - 1\choose 179}={179 + i\choose 179}$$
And let's to the same thing for student who go between $120-i$ and $100$ inclusive: $${179 + (100 - (120 - i) + 1) - 1\choose 179}={159 + i\choose 179}$$
Multiplying both results since they come one after the other and summing it all up, we end up with: $$\sum_{i=20}^{60}{179 + i\choose 179}{159 + i\choose 179}$$
Now, as I asked at the beggining of the question, I would like to know if there is a solution not using sums, but a closed a formula. Thanks to the helpers.
P.S. We haven't learned about generating functions, yet.

Are you asking for the number of distributions or histograms (i.e. is the bin size 1)?

By a histograms, I mean a sequence of $100$ bins, such that each bin can contain (theoretically) infinite values. For example, a distribution of $10$ students into a histogram of grade $0-100$, could be to put $3$ of them into grade $50$, $1$ into grade $62$, $4$ into grade $93$, $1$ into grade $98$ and $1$ into grade $100$.

How many ways can you put the top 50 students into the 40 bins (above 60)?  How many ways can you put the bottom 50 students into the 60 bins (below 60)?  Multiply those two numbers.

@DavidG.Stork it's not that simple. The fact that the median is 60 does not imply that the middle numbers are 60, as we are talking about an even numbers of students. It could be 40 and 80, 30 and 70, and a bunch of other options, ad I did in my attempt.

@natitati:  What the median value means is that half of the students' grades are greater than 60 and have the students' grades are lower than 60.  Clear?

@David: that's not right and natitati is right here. With an odd number of students the median would be the middle value. With an even number of students there are two middle values and the median is their arithmetic mean.

Anyone? Do you guys know the answer or can refer me to a similar problem?
